# Changing form label (No ID or class) via script

Tags: javascript, forms, label

I have a form in one of my apps:

```
<div class="custom-form-field">
    <label>
        Email
        <span class="required-asterix"></span>
    </label>
    <input name="email" class="email" type="email" placeholder="Work Email" tabindex="0" value="">
</div>
```

I have the ability to run a custom script in the header or the body of the page, and I would like to change the label from "Email" to "Company email".

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: That label is kinda useless since it is not related to the input in any way

Comment: `.custom-form-field label` ?

Answer (score 1):

To match an element by its contents you'll need to use XPath.

```js
let emailLabels = document.evaluate( "//div[contains(@class, 'custom-form-field')]/label[contains(., 'Email')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

let label = emailLabels.iterateNext();

label.innerText = "Company Email";
```

```html
<div class="custom-form-field">
    <label>
        Email
        <span class="required-asterix"></span>
    </label>
    <input name="email" class="email" type="email" placeholder="Work Email" tabindex="0" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native javascript, can try this:

```html
<div class="custom-form-field"><label>Email<span class="required-asterix"></span></label><input name="email" class="email  " type="email" placeholder="Work Email" tabindex="0" value=""></div>
<script>
  custom_field = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-form-field');
  custom_field[0].children[0].outerText = 'Company Email';
</script>
```